# random "data-v-*" attribute in Vue.js components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Experimenting with [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/) the first thing I noticed is how every instance of a component that I define as [single file component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) and include as custom element gets a random hash attribute like `data-v-58fd7087=""`.
Specifically:

- Every DOM element of every instance of a given component gets the same hash
- The hash is generated independently of the router
- The hash is stable between calls
- The hash is stable between name changes of the component
- The hash is not stored / generated on the disk
- Thus the hash is generated dynamically

Could it be generated by [Karma](https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/index.html) or [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org) that are part of my Vue setup?
If not, these are some surprising observations to me. It leads to two questions:

- When and how is this hash (attribute) generated?
- Why is the hash (attribute) generated?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Something similar occurs when using [scoped CSS](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/features/scoped-css.html) with Vue Loader.

I use scoped css and I have attributes like `data-v-4646bc3c`, so I figure that is it.

If you don't want this feature, try removing the `scoped` attribute from your single file components.

```
<style scoped>
/* local styles */
</style>
```

Comment: You are right! So actually the `data-v-*` attributes come from the vue CSS loader, if and only if using `scoped` CSS. They are being used as selectors to apply the CSS. Nice, thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to change this default behavior while still using scoped CSS ? Because it ends up with much bigger CSS files to load and parse...!

Comment: @ekqnp: No - this is how scopes work, they need the hashes as selectors.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `vueify` and you're wondering why you are getting changes in your build without having changed anything, make sure you are running vueify with the `process.env.NODE_ENV` set to `'production'`. Otherwise it generates hot-reload code that has new `data-v-*` hashes on every build.

Comment: Do u have any idea to remove data-v-*